# Angular Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only disallowed in meta tag

Tags: angular, content-security-policy

I'm trying to enable a content security policy in report-only mode for an Angular application but when I try to inject it via the meta tag I get a disallowed message in Chrome (v64).

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only" content="default-src 'self'" />
```

> The report-only Content Security Policy 'default-src 'self'' was delivered via a  element, which is disallowed. The policy has been ignored.

I've also tried with Edge (v41) and Firefox (v59) where there is no error but also no console output. Have I missed a configuration step or is there a workaround?

Comment: Here is a workaround with Javascript: [Content Security Policy (CSP): Is it somehow possible to report violations if using meta tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75616817/1066234)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only` policy can only be specified with an HTTP response header. The [CSP spec explicitly disallows if from from being specified with a `meta` element](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/#meta-element):

> Note: The `Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only` header is not supported inside a `meta` element. Neither are the `report-uri`, `frame-ancestors`, and `sandbox` directives.

There is no workaround other than to specify it using an HTTP response header instead.

Answer (score 0):

Old thread but, in Angular 8, adding the meta Content-Security-Policy does report any errors to the console in Chrome debugger tools.  I added it to the index.html file.